# Selecting Image Src From XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a basic RSS feed but I have images within the description.  Is there anyway of selecting the img src with XSLT?

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img src="http://www.sitename.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/MyImage31-150x150.jpg"/>
Content is here.
]]>
</description>
```

Comment: I think that this kind of question deserves its own "don't parse (X)HTML with RegExp" kind of answer...

Comment: There is no `image` element having `src` attribute in your input sample. CDATA sections are just unparsed text. Try to not use unparsed data as parseable data, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not a complete answer, but is too long to fit as a comment. The following selects the URL from the given example (if each description contains only one `img`. Otherwise you can make a separate template and call it recursively to select all the `img`s):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/description/text()">
        <xsl:value-of
            select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;img src=&quot;'), '&quot;/>')"
            disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think there is a way to make a node-set from the string (but I don't know, you can do some research on it), so you can make a node-set from `<img .../>` and get the `src` attribute value.

Comment: Any way you can expand on this.  I'm sort of lost on how to do this.

Comment: You wrote: *I think there is a way to make a node-set from the string*. Yes, it is called parser. `node-set()` extension function only works with Result Tree Fragment. DOE mechanism won't help either: a RTF containing a text node would be converted to a text node singleton node set, it wouldn't be parsed.